# How to get the correct type of a Typescript function argument based on another argument's generic type?

Tags: typescript

I tried to find other answers but could not find any solution to this very simple problem so I am sure I am missing something obvious.

I have a function that takes in a generic argument that can be either `string` or `number` and based on the type of this argument, the second argument will have a specific type. The code is very simple:

```
type OptionsNumber = {
  numberProp: number
}

type OptionsString = {
  stringProp: string
}

export const test = <T extends number | string>(
  input: T | undefined | null,
  options?: T extends string
    ? OptionsString
    : T extends number
    ? OptionsNumber 
    : never
): void => {
  if (typeof input === 'number') {
    // I am getting an error below because TypeScript is not able to apply the `OptionsNumber` type
    console.log(options.numberProp)
  }
}
```

Working code here: https://tsplay.dev/w17rAm

Basically, all I am hoping is that by checking the type of `input` TypeScript can know that `options` have the right type (just like in the `options` conditional type.

What am I missing?

Comment: Type narrowing works on the variables, not on the types themself. Once past the header of the function, there is no way for the compiler to link a narrowing on `input` to a narrowing on `options`.

Comment: Oh really, so this is just not possible and I need to use casting?

Comment: There are multiple problems here. Control flow analysis does not affect type parameters; checking `input` does not touch `T`; there's a feature request for this at [ms/TS#33014](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014). And `number` is not a discriminant property of a discriminated union, so narrowing `input` to `number` will have no effect on `options` [even if you remove the generics](//tsplay.dev/WKOjpW).   ...

Comment: ... Non-discriminated unions lose benefits (like [destructuring support](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) . You can use custom type guard functions, but to you need to guard `[input, options]` as a single variable, like [this](//tsplay.dev/WY3b2N). It's ugly. Does this fully address your question? If so I can write this up as an actual answer; if not, what am I missing? Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me.

Comment: Yes thanks @jcalz - I guess until this feature request would be. implemented, the most likely best option we have right now is using type casting?

Comment: I assume by "casting" you mean "assertions".  Assertions are easy to use but I don't know if it's the "best" option because it doesn't help with type safety.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance (assuming that's what you want)

Comment: Sorry @jcalz I meant force casting. In my original example I could do `console.log((options as OptionsNumber).numberProp)`

Comment: Yes, that's called [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  The term "casting" is ambiguous and generally avoided in TypeScript because often people think of *runtime coercion* which is different.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz - looking forward to see your answer

Comment: I am backlogged at the moment so I might not get to this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might be simple, but the issues it raises are not. There are multiple problems that unfortunately stop it from working.

---

The first is that [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) does not affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type* parameters.  When you check `input` with `typeof input === 'number'`, the compiler will narrow the type of `input` from `T` to `T & number` (thanks to [support for narrowing values of generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics) added in TypeScript 4.3):

```
if (typeof input === 'number') {
  input; // (parameter) input: T & number
}
```

but *nothing happens to `T`*.  The type of `T` does not get "re-constrained" to `T extends number`.  And since `T` does not get narrowed, the type of `options` is unchanged.  It can still be some subtype of `OptionsString | OptionsNumber`.

There are open feature requests asking for something better here, such as  [ms/TS#33014](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014). But for now this is a design limitation of TypeScript.

---

Given your call signature, though, you don't need this to be generic.  You could make the function arguments a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types), and you can even [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that into the original `input` and `options` parameters:

```
export const test = (...[input, options]:
  [input: string, options?: OptionsString] |
  [input: number, options?: OptionsNumber]
): void => { /* snip */ }

test("abc", { stringProp: "def" }); // okay
test(123, { numberProp: 456 }); // okay
test("abc", { numberProp: 456 }); // error!
```

From the caller's side, this is just as good as the generic version.  Unfortunately, your implementation problem persists:

```
export const test = (...[input, options]:
  [input: string, options?: OptionsString] |
  [input: number, options?: OptionsNumber]
): void => {
  if (typeof input === 'number') {
    console.log(options?.numberProp) // still error!
  }
}
```

---

So that's the second problem.  Even if you could narrow `T`, it would fail, because the type of argument pair `[input, options]` is *not* considered to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) by the compiler.

A discriminated union needs a *discriminant property* whose type is a singleton/unit/[literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or a union of such types, in at least one of the union members.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#48500](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48500#issuecomment-1085063454) for a source for that.)

Then when you check the discriminant property, it will narrow the rest of the properties via control flow analysis.  And even in the case of destructured assignment to separate variables like `input` and `options`, this control flow analysis still works, thanks to [support added in TypeScript 4.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).

So if `input` were of a literal type like, say, `"abc"` or `123`, this would magically work:

```
export const test = (...[input, options]:
  [input: "abc", options?: OptionsString] |
  [input: 123, options?: OptionsNumber]
): void => {
  if (input === 123) {
    console.log(options?.numberProp) // okay!
  }
}
```

But the type of `input` is either `string` or `number`.  These are *not* discriminant types, and so checking them does not do anything to the apparent type of the pair `[input, options]`.  You can check `input` all you like, and it will never have an effect on the apparent type of `options`.

---

You can try to work around that by writing a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that acts on the rest argument, where you explicitly tell the compiler how to narrow it:

```
function firstElementIsNumber(x: object): x is { 0: number } {
  return typeof (x as any)[0] === "number";
}
```

If you call `firstElementIsNumber(something)` and it returns `true`, then the compiler will narrow the apparent type of `something` to a type with a `number` property at index `0`.  Otherwise it will try to narrow `something` to a type without such a property.  Let's test it:

```
export const test = (...args:
  [input: string, options?: OptionsString] |
  [input: number, options?: OptionsNumber]
): void => {
  if (firstElementIsNumber(args)) {
    const [input, options] = args;
    console.log(options?.numberProp) // okay
  } else {
    const [input, options] = args;
    console.log(options?.stringProp) // okay
  }
}
```

So that works just fine, hooray!  Except, uh, it's kind of ugly.  It's still impossible to write `if (someTest(input)) { options?.numberProp }`, because `input` has no effect on `options`.  We have to leave `args` as a tuple type, test that tuple, and *then* destructure it into variables if we want.

That's about the best I can do if I want type safety from the compiler.  The only unsafe code is that the compiler doesn't check the implementation of `firstElementIsNumber()` (custom type guard functions are never checked for anything except that they return a `boolean`), but as long as that's properly implemented then you can be fairly confident in the type safety of the `test()` function.

---

Since you can't do this ergonomically, then you will need to choose between style and safety.  You always have the option of leaving your code mostly the same, and using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just *tell* the compiler what the type of `options` should be:

```
export const test = <T extends number | string>(
  input: T | undefined | null,
  options?: T extends string ? OptionsString : T extends number ? OptionsNumber : never
): void => {
  if (typeof input === 'number') {        
    console.log((options as OptionsNumber | undefined)?.numberProp)
  } else {
    console.log((options as OptionsString | undefined)?.stringProp)
  }
}
```

That compiles without error, and emits the same JavaScript as your original version.  But remember, this is not verified as safe, it's just you making a claim about the types.  You could make the wrong claim and the compiler wouldn't catch it:

```
export const test = <T extends number | string>(
  input: T | undefined | null,
  options?: T extends string ? OptionsString : T extends number ? OptionsNumber : never
): void => {
  if (typeof input !== 'number') { // 
    console.log((options as OptionsNumber | undefined)?.numberProp)
  } else {
    console.log((options as OptionsString | undefined)?.stringProp)
  }
}
```

So if you decide to use type assertions, be careful!

---

There you have it! Your problem was very simple, and the answer involves something like three separate design limitations of TypeScript and references to them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJIAuAnjMgPIykCWA9sFAHICuYARhAE5IBePERIlgnHrwAKvRjABcScdz4ikAXyJqKVJLQbMoAZVK96wAOaDhxUVFPmLMuYvtnLazYS23QkWAjIAOIQwHz08DZqJBAAHjCMvKRI8IbJpNDJQgA8ACpIcRnAACZQShJ8SAA+SG6OAHwAFNGi5jDspIr5NewlEABm5hDF1eUYGAA0LSRyBiwA-F0FsUWltQ6WSPN6dEwsJu5WS4Wha8qSWztzbBX8imEAbqq2JACUig+M9CMC9TairX6SEaOggjCBbQ6ggEQgA5Oc+LDXv8Aa1gO1SABuJAAehxwLgvHAEAyvGRkM6SHyADJyipeNNRHikABJJDgJAWEkMTYgYAFXiyfg8DCMADuSB46HYUGQuUoECM8DMdCQ9DKwEYyRAXAwyFIjHZMBgGHIZAAFsgAAb6PY3elWsgKxkkVIsRh6gB0oosjVmdvmnoR0lkMFejK8AK8nh8YmJAUQSAAqsA9qxmAARdXK+hgFExeKJZJu+xkTLWRqeqsAbQpEyQ-sMAF15Iza+iOq4NhZ642FopbYYDo4m9U2xT7rde7tDIsrnaOPSmy13khPt9BH8CC9AcDQeC1R2sjCkPDbkj86iSx6IN7GL6+1BA8HnGHcfj7PRxgKhQBCCMtNGO4ZPYjQAEQ6vAYH1rg6yHK+ihgcUAxgRorzYsyjAANYgOQLQgaQjQAIwAEwAMwwXSkgIUgAAsACsABsaEYfi2G4fhmTgZB0F4FRfA0QxzHqOh74-ok-7eFJMbSb48ZwImKZ7FmUA5nm24AnECRJCkaRlqWQiVjWdYNjOLAtuOR6ITx07XHOg77N2o5VJZGKKKRFGmXZA5mfakjLjuq7rj8W6MvQQKNBS0JCB5yIaairqGDed4Pr5z63K+yKYTh5CSQlkaiEBAIEdxXBQZRdSWDRSEoSxYnsXhwFcR5lEvqGihCXV2UcU1oEQWVvGwW1Lh0UxXX4nwf4+LGGgzX40AKcgADCMoGmA8pUEE7AgLwIzbjNJD9L08BzEggy8PYACieqQMApAsn5fCNLEiiMFwABWEAnausRqmUsEAAyTvSGiXiQvAkuwvD8vuEW-SAZR8uQrzVgDo4wkIYHBmBmKAQdyzacWekERWVaejtFhQK2O4kO2blwY4tkBj51zDpYzmuZ2-G8Ezs4swutwBQCQVfCFYNqhF51XTdoT3Y9vCNBTUCvHFLq6SwyR0x0vPmdYSu4zTojXl6Pp+mlQYZaGWVsTlEYFBgsri4lGtIFrpA61A6PsrwlMGwlztQMlpuPoGlVOFb9W24bBUkAVRVKPJgRIAAglAso6ftO5aUW6uliTOT5CcJQarcoxh00YVWVSoy9MhgxhCMNTiOMUyGyHxwrKcZRh5cDnGN2SAd6sJcg9sfeLhc9wQE8DKBR8oubuL4V7gqB5RRjp7Bhe8UJcbt6m2b1zsmU4+lz0fT18MrzpfSmV2xADvIDvV5JSb96NIfdrH-OQ4D+fddDGKNfT0Yc77RzxlJWOc1E6JlTunUg1A5D-XxtnHSJZ0jlgLssYe3My7dgrobCc1d-4DEAaMZukxGTt2rkXNYPcx6+TZkcGhndi64IYdcCelQp4zxXPPDcvwl4RVhoeDESBfwnjPPSbeYlAC8G4ARj21Z7xSh-R839T4gxIZfIBN9qJW3vo-J2ucg7v0-oYdRjC-5IFrqQhuwDQH6PATueOQF1BAA)

Comment: Thanks amazing answer - I hope this helps others as well!